# Hint to linux to not interrupt thread?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I launch a thread for each core on my machine. Each thread will run a critical function 1-5 times. I tested by using the same data on the function. I measured each run about 95-170 milliseconds. Being 78% slower on some runs is pretty huge and by profiling it seems that it's because the function is interrupted and the data is no longer in cache (including data on the stack).

Can I tell the kernel to interrupt 1 of my threads but don't interrupt the others? Then maybe swap which one should be interrupted once a thread is complete?

Comment: You can set signal handling per thread to selectively ignore actual signals.  You can use process scheduling functions to affect how processes are scheduled (which is possibly the sort of 'interrupt' you're thinking of) — but you may or may not be able to formally prevent the kernel from scheduling your threads over multiple timeslices.  You'll need to read the manual pages very carefully.

Comment: 78% difference is probably not due to cache. Linux scheduler probably even does not dispatch your threads evenly one thread per core. He may give two/three threads on the same core and schedule them one after another in time slices. During this your threads may even be moved from one core to another as the scheduler decides. Browse things around the keyword "thread affinity" to get better control of your execution.

Comment: By "interrupt", do you mean processing an actual hardware interrupt? Or do you mean the kernel interrupts your thread's execution to allow some other thread to run?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What functions do you have in mind? I'll try sched_setscheduler this week

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the latter. I imagine anything that'll affect the cache before the function is done will hurt but I don't think my hardware is messing with my threads

Comment: You can use the POSIX [`pthread_sigmask()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_sigmask.html) function to control per-thread signal masking. You can use the POSIX `sched_*()` functions (e.g. [`sched_setparam()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sched_setparam.html) and [`sched_setscheduler()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sched_setscheduler.html)) to alter the scheduling behaviour. As I noted, I don't think you can prevent the kernel from forcing your threads to yield. Look for Linux-specific functions too.

Comment: @David It sounds like you just want to increase the thread's priority then so that the scheduler will not pre-empt it to run a thread with a higher priority.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that there are probably a number of other things going on here which could affect your app's performance, plenty of data you haven't provided to us, and other options to affect things in your favour (i.e. Linux scheduling).  But if you're convinced that interrupt handling plays a significant role in your performance issue, then yes you can manage that - at a price.

To schedule only particular cores to receive and handle interrupts (leaving the remaining cores free for you to run your app threads on uninterrupted), try playing with the **smp_affinity** settings as described [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/performance_tuning_guide/s-cpu-irq).  I'd suggest you look into disabling any irq balancing that Linux tries to do on its own (see irqbalance(8)) and then allocate the interrupt affinities as you wish.  Good luck with your app development!